# Azure function Startup Microsoft.Extensions.Http 8.0.0 could not load

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm using an Azure Function v4 .net6 project, that is running locally for now.

I'm trying to use Microsoft.Extensions.Http to add my `HttpClient` as according to:
[functions-dotnet-dependency-injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) and [correct-way-to-use-http-client-in-azure-functions](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/correct-way-to-use-http-client-in-azure-functions)

This is my Startup:

```cs
using DinersService.Helpers;
using DinersService.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(DinersService.Startup))]
namespace DinersService
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiClient, ApiClient>();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http 6.0.0 it works fine and all is good.

However when I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http 7.0.0 or higher it breaks and gives me the following errors:

`Error configuring services in an external startup class. DinersService: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. [2023-12-13T10:19:39.349Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '628e8d49-0172-4230-a0e3-861455a94086'. [2023-12-13T10:19:39.350Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. DinersService: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`

Comment: Can you please share .csproj file?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I've edited the post so that it contains the csproj now.

Comment: Why not just to install matching versions of the packages or update runtime to .NET 8?

Comment: @MikkelRohdeGlerup It looks like `Using >=7.X version dependencies are not supported in V4 in-proc model. This is a limitation of the in-proc model in V4 running on .NET 6`, refer this github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8984#issuecomment-1571075265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `Microsoft.Extensions.Http 7.0.0 , 8.0.0` at my end and got the same error.

***.csproj***-

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_77652797</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

By downgrading to 6.0.0 version worked for me.

> When I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http 6.0.0 it works fine and all is good. However when I use Microsoft.Extensions.Http 7.0.0 or higher it breaks and gives me Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0 error.

I came across this [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8984#issuecomment-1571075265), which says its a limitation in in-process function wherein >=7.X version dependencies are not supported for V4 in-process azure functions.

[image]

It is recommended to use [Isolated function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) if you intend to use 7.x or higher version dependencies.

If you still want to use in-process function, then as you stated `Microsoft.Extensions.Http 6.0.0` works for you, you can continue using 6.x version.

***References***-

[Azure Function and Entity Framework Sql Server error - Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0 · Issue #2319 · Azure/Azure-Functions · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2319#issuecomment-1378025573).